# Same asserts for every scenario can be put in a separate file to avoid duplication in karate?

Tags: karate

Here are two scenarios , One after the other

```
Scenario: Positive - Create a discount with ABSOLUTE discount and ROOM_NIGHT_PRICE and search 

Given url baseUrl + SEARCH
And request changes
When method post
Then status 200 

And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].discount_id == discountId
And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].code == couponCode
And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].discount_value ==  incentive_value
And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounted_sell_price == (sellPrice-incentive_value)

Scenario: Positive - Create a discount with ABSOLUTE discount and TRANSACTION_PRICE and search 

Given url baseUrl + SEARCH
And request changes
When method post
Then status 200 

And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].discount_id == discountId
And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].code == couponCode
And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].discount_value ==  incentive_value
And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounted_sell_price == (sellPrice-incentive_value)
```

If you notice that assertions are same for these scenarios , I have similar 20 scenarios with exactly same assertions , Can I put it in a separate file to avoid duplication and easy to maintain ?

If Yes then how ? 
If No then is there any other way to avoid duplication in karate

Comment: I haven't put the whole code to avoid confusion , But 2 scenarios are different other than the values it asserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any change on your request either.

If only change in your scenarios are payload

You can try using `Scenario Outline:`
and pass different payloads from `Examples:` table

```
Scenario Outline: Positive - Create a discount and search 
 Given url baseUrl + SEARCH 
 And request <changes> 
 When method post 
 Then status 200 
 And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].discount_id == discountId      
 And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].code == couponCode  
 And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounts[0].discount_value == incentive_value  
 And match $.data.hotels[0].transaction_discount.discounted_sell_price == (sellPrice-incentive_value)
Examples:
|  changes  |
|RNP_PAYLOAD|
|TXP_PAYLOAD|
```

you can create these payloads instances in `Background:`, this could help you avoid scenario duplication.

**OR**

If your intention is still to have this on a separate file

You can create a feature file which takes both expected and actual JSON as an input and perform match operation in it.

Then you can call that feature file in all of your scenarios passing the values to the calling feature.

Comment: My questions was I want to keep assertions in a separate file , Is that possible ?

Comment: @SourabhChapali - keep in mind these are tests not production code. duplication is ok to a certain extent. because of how easy it is to write assertions. from experience, the moment you start trying to add layers, you introduce other problems. but yes - if you really want to - just move all the assertions to a separate feature file (single scenario) and do a `call`